# Aligning 2 pictures next to each other by using the class of the parent element

Tags: html, css, image

I want to make a picture of 1 star arranged into 6 stars
by selecting the class of the parent element.

```css
.stars {
  /* what tag can use? */
}
```

```html
<div class="stars">
  <img src="image/stars.jpeg">
  <img src="image/stars.jpeg">
  <img src="image/stars.jpeg">
  <img src="image/stars.jpeg">
  <img src="image/stars.jpeg">
  <img src="image/stars.jpeg">
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: the images are `inline`-elements and as such should be displayed next to each other by default (given that the available width is sufficient)

Comment: try `display: flex`

Answer (score -1):

On the parent element, you can use:

```
display: flex;
```

You find a detailed explanation to flex boxes here:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: not necessary on inline-elements such as pictures. They align horizontally next to each other by default.

Comment: Well, since he asked the question, it implies, it does not have the default behavior (probably because of css  code we don't see here). So some action is necessary. Making the children inline, or inline-block or making the parent a flex element, all work. And all are correct. Based on my experience, i prefer the flex solution, because it results in cleaner code.

Comment: like I said, it does that by default so no reason to add flexbox. Instead of answering you should have flagged for missing debugging details and/or for being not reproducible.